# How to layout complete graphs circularly using Dot and Graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

How can I layout nodes in a graph "circularly", similar to the graphs in the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graphviz offers the [*circo* layout engine](http://graphviz.org/pdf/circo.1.pdf) for circular layouts.

> circo draws graphs using a circular layout (see Six and Tollis, GD ’99
>   and ALENEX ’99, and Kaufmann and Wiese, GD ’02.) The tool identifies
>   biconnected components and draws the nodes of the component on a
>   circle. The block-cutpoint tree is then laid out using a recursive
>   radial algorithm. Edge crossings within a circle are minimized by
>   placing as many edges on the circle’s perimeter as possible. In
>   particular, if the component is outerplanar, the component will have a
>   planar layout. If a node belongs to multiple non-trivial biconnected
>   components, the layout puts the node in one of them. By default, this
>   is the first non-trivial component found in the search from the root
>   component.

A simple example for K3 would be:

```
graph K3 {
    layout=circo;
    node[shape=point, color=red];
    a--b--c--a;
}
```

However, most of the graphs will be oriented differently than on your image. The K3 example would yield this:

[image: K3]

To test other layout engines online you can use [GraphvizOnline](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/).